# how to download a tablet emulator for Android lollipop 5.0 API 21

Tags: android, emulation, tablet

i need to download a tablet emulator for Android lollipop 5.0 API 21
I've searched for this but in vain :S

any help ?

Answer (score 1):

There are no special downloads for tablet emulator.

You can emulate a tablet using a standard Android emulator included into SDK - just select "tablet" from "device Category" on "device definition" screen of wizard.

Please take a look on https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds.html